# Should you still support IE conditional comments?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

As a lone developer with limited resources, I made the decision some time ago not to continue support for IE8 and IE9.

To manage the situation I use IE's conditional comments - I now also use Modernizr to detect support for individual features, which the above browers do  not support anyway.

Javascript is also a given for me - if you don't have it, then sorry but we can't do business.

I was therefore considering removing conditional comments and letting Modernizr/javascript do the job.

Conditional comments do break a lot of things that scrape the site - for instance CopyScape will not work - there's also testing software I use that breaks and/or gives out false signals.

Does anyone have any cast iron reasons NOT TO remove them or TO remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that support for conditional comments was [removed from IE10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx), I would recommend against using them at this point in time.  It's 2017; time to move on.  (That's my take, anyway; YMMV.)

I would consider providing a bare bones version of the site designed for any browser other than your preferred one (which, conveniently, also helps you support experiences you didn't plan for).

Comment: I agree with you Lance but since I live in my little bubble it's always good to get other peoples opinions. I've tussled with the bare bones stuff - as a lone developer, it's difficult to justify works arounds for a minority audience - I require Ajax, use Html5 features etc. - and as you said, it's 2017, not 2009.

Comment: Absolutely respect that.  However, considering that earlier versions of IE have increasing small shares of the market (including less than 3% [according to one source](https://clicky.com/marketshare/global/web-browsers/internet-explorer/)), the investment value really doesn't seem to be there any longer.  (And, yes, I know there are other sources, but they require subscriptions I don't have.  The numbers seem similar, though.)